# Agregar línea Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Tengo este código

```
    <script>
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);
function drawStacked() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Ventas', 'Ventas Totales de Marzo', { role: 'style' }, 'Ventas faltantes para la Meta', { role: 'style'  }],
        //['', 50, 250 ],
        ['Ventas', 10, '#CE023F', 20,  '#102A47'],
      ]);
      var options = {
        title: '',
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2},
        colors: ['#CE023F', '#102A47',],
        chartArea: {width: '60%'},
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          title: ' ',
          minValue: 0,
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: ' '
        },
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_Ventas'));
      chart.draw(data,options);
    }
</script>
```

Necesito que aparezca una línea vertical roja en el punto 30. Me ayudan de favor?

https://jsfiddle.net/rthz1jkx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiqué tu jsfiddle original para incluir la línea; puedes [verlo aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/rthz1jkx/1/). Básicamente utilicé una funcionalidad del mismo API de Google Charts para dibujar elementos sobrepuestos (*overlays*) sobre las gráficas. Puedes leer dicha documentación [aquí](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays).

Es probable que tengas que ajustar el código CSS para posicionar el div (`#vert_marker`) de acuerdo a tu situación real (y no dentro del jsfiddle), pero en general debería funcionar porque la función `placeMarker` obtiene la ubicación final del mismo gráfico, independientemente de dónde se pinte. Para probar lo anterior puedes cambiar las opciones para que utilice un ancho mayor (en vez del 60% especificado) y debería dibujarse la línea roja correctamente. Por ejemplo:

```
chartArea: {
  width: '90%'
},
```

**Nota:** Si deseas cambiar el ancho de la línea, color y/o altura, simplemente cambia las propiedades correspondientes en el CSS (en este caso `width`, `background-color` y `height`) por los valores deseados.

Espero que te funcione. Saludos.